# validation in javascript is not validating the function

Tags: javascript

I am validating a form which has validations for required field, character, number, email, password format, length of a field.

In my code, required field and length are working but the rest.

JavaScript code for Password format:

```
function CheckPassword(paswd) {
    var submitFlag = false;
    var paswd = /^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*_])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]{7,15}$/;
    if (document.reg_indi_form.pswd.length > 0) {
        if (!document.reg_indi_form.pswd.value.match(paswd)) {
            submitFlag = true;
            document.getElementById('i3').innerHTML = "Use atleast one digit,character,specialCharacter";
            document.getElementById('i3').style.color = "red";
            document.getElementById('i10').style.fontSize = "12px";
            //return false;  
        }
    }
    return submitFlag;
}

function alls() {
    var valid = true;
    valid *= req();
    valid *= validateUname();
    valid *= CheckPassword(this);
    valid *= num();
    valid *= confirm_pswd();
    valid *= namevalid();
    valid *= ValidateEmail(this);
    return valid ? true : false;
}
```

I am calling `alls()` on `onSubmit`.
All other functions which are not working are similar to `checkPassword()`.

HTML code:

```
<form name="reg_indi_form" method="post" onSubmit="return alls()" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <table height="100" width="1000">
        <tr>
            <td>
                First Name<font color="#FF0000">*</font>: 
             </td>
             <td>
                 <input name="txt_fnm" type="text" id="txt_fnm"/> <label id="i"></label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Password<font color="#FF0000">*</font>: 
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="password" name="pswd" id="pswd"/><label id="i3"></label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    </form>
```

Comment: You pass paswd as an argument and then you overwrite it's value with the regex, how are you going to validate the password?

Comment: but this function works individually when i call it in onSubmit.

Comment: Please post the corresponding HTML.

Comment: In addition to posting the corresponding HTML, please provide which browsers you are testing this in.

Comment: i am testing in chrome.

Comment: What do you expect CheckPassword(this) to do?

Comment: it will validate the password which user has enter. is it wrong?

Comment: document.reg_indi_form.pswd ? What is this?

Answer (score 0):

**Considering** that your `CheckPassword()` returns true when the password is correct.

Now in your `CheckPassword()` function, `document.reg_indi_form.pswd.value.match(paswd)` this statement returns true if the pattern matches. You have added `!` means it will return true when password doesn't matches to the given pattern. I have edited the function below, also consider using boolean operators instead of using multiple/nested if statements where ever possible. You don't have any field with id **i10** I think it should be **i3** instead.

```
function CheckPassword() {
    var submitFlag = false;
    var paswd = /^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*_])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]{7,15}$/;
    if ((document.reg_indi_form.pswd.length > 0) && (document.reg_indi_form.pswd.value.match(paswd))) {
        submitFlag = true;
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById('i3').innerHTML = "Use atleast one digit,character,specialCharacter";
        document.getElementById('i3').style.color = "red";
        document.getElementById('i3').style.fontSize = "12px";
    }
    return submitFlag;
}
```

And finally why are you using *= operator for boolean values in your `alls()` function? You should use boolean operator. Also `this` passes the current form or field object to the function, it is not required in this context since you are using `document.formName.fieldName` to access the fields of the form. Also the ternary (bool?value1:value2) operator at the end is unnecessary.

```
function alls() {
    var valid = req()
    && validateUname()
    && CheckPassword()
    && num()
    && confirm_pswd()
    && namevalid()
    && ValidateEmail();

    return valid;
}
```

Comment: this code works when i apply it to checkPassword.  but its not working when i apply this logic to multiple functions.